# Draw column chart using grouped data in Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I want to draw a column chart which represent below mentioned kind of data structure.

Marks-Range -> count

(0-20) ->  8

(20-40) ->  15

(40-60)  -> 20

(60-80) ->  7

(80-100) -> 4

But the values i have is set of marks. (10,15,45,80....)

It is true that, this type of chart can be drawn in hi-charts by grouping those data manually. The problem is, once you do that you can't draw a plot line for x axis. I wonder is there any way to draw it by providing a grouping method like 'sum' similarly to data grouping option in [Hi-stock](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation) charts. I can't use Hi-stock chart since my x values are not related to data or time.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste your data, chart configuration or  something?

Comment: HI Sebastian, We used this manual method of grouping and able to draw the required chart. But i wanted to know if this can be done in a way similar to  hi-stock chart grouping.

Comment: The datagrouping is available only in the highstock, not in the higcharts. So you need to calculate it on your own or replace with HS.